# Bullet btGImpactCollisionAlgorithm

Tags: performance, bullet-physics, aabb

I have a question about Bullet and in particular GImpact.

When, the collisiontestpair(a, b) is called where GImpact pair check algo will be called on the 
btGImpactMeshShape, does it do a AABB tree vs. AABB tree to get to the leaf level, worstcase O(N*N) OR is it O(N*N) triangle wise collision check.

Thank you.